# Google Drive The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I have created a Google Service account and I use it with Python using the Pydrive2 library. From my Python script I upload folders and files on a specific folder in the drive. The folder in the drive is owned by a Standard Account but the content inside that folder is owned by the Service Account. Now, when I try to upload something using my Python script I get the following error.

```
'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded', 'message': 'The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota'
```

The error says that the user has exceeded their Drive storage quota but when I upload a file manually on the same drive it works and doesn't throw an error.